# What are the non-hotel options for a 3-month stay in the Greater Toronto Area?

Tags: canada, rental, toronto

I need to stay in Toronto / GTA region for 3 months(during this winter season). What are the options apart from Hotels because it could be costly and apartments usually have a lease for 12 months.

Is it possible to rent just for 3 months?

Comment: Have you looked at Airbnb or similar sites?

Comment: @EMotion - I haven't looked into Airbnb. I am not aware of the same. I will look into it

Comment: @pnuts - I am new to the country and I only know of the two options either renting an apartment or going for hotel. I am not sure of other options. IMHO then it is not a broad question...

Comment: just go to holiday-rentals.com

Comment: no worries.  as others have said "airBNB" is just the "modern, hip" version of holiday-rentals.  purely one man's opinion, as a rule holiday-rentals is better for LONGER rentals.  (airBNB is somewhat focussed on overnights.)  Note - with anyone you find on holiday-rentals or VRBO, very simply email them ***and ask for a price for a longer deal***.  You will pay ***FAR*** less per week than their usual weekly rate.  it's totally common.  you do need to GET IN EARLY, though.  enjoy.

Comment: this question is neither broad nor subjective. indeed it has a very specific answer.  but I believe it is an exact duplicate (but I can't be bothered looking up the dupe.)  Regarding "no research" - we just have to let go of that.  Simple Facts!  (1) nobody does research anymore, they just post on an SO site  (2) SO'ers love answering such questions, they ALWAYS get answered in the face of of "no research" complaints (3) it's not even clear that SO policy is against "you could have googled" QA. it's great to have a "definitive answer" online.  And SO want it, so as to make more money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start looking at places like [AirBnB](http://www.airbnb.com), [VRBO](http://www.vrbo.com), [Kijiji](http://www.kijiji.ca) for places that allow renting monthly, since it is quite likely that they will let you stay for more than one month.

I have previously successfully rented a place for friends on [VRBO](http://www.vrbo.com) though not in Greater Toronto Area